# How to use custom constraints in workmanager in android

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I want to use custom constraints in workmanager. Custom constraint will check if network is connected and there is Internet access only then start worker.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. To increase the chance of answers to your question, please read the following HowToAskAQuestion: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Custom `Constraints` for that.

Just use the `Constraints.Builder` and set Network required to `CONNECTED`.

i.e:

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build();
```

And afterwards use this constraint for your Request. 
Like in:

```
new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(YourClass.class).setConstraint(constraints);
```

Comment: Thank you. I know this. But I want to handle the case when network is connected but no internet access.

Comment: Well, then you will get a timeout and should return Result.RETRY

Comment: For checking if your client is not only connected to a network, but to "the internet" - the only possibility is to check if it can connect to a server - which you would need to create.